# Retrofit 500 response during get

Tags: android, rest, api, retrofit

I'm trying to build an android application and i got a 500 response during  GET action,the request work perfectly and return 200 in postman.
Here is my code,its in the on create function.

```
 try {

                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.setConnectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES); // connect timeout
                client.setReadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(LoginActivity.adresseLocal).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).client(client)
                        .build();
                APIService service = retrofit.create(APIService.class);
                Call<List<Limit>> call1 = service.getLimit(pf.getString("ip",""),pf.getString("login",""),pf.getString("password",""),pf.getString("database",""), "792EE098-A158-4197-B6B9-23BD95D4F58B", "2", "2");

                call1.enqueue(new Callback<List<Limit>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Response<List<Limit>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

                        System.out.println("respooooonse" + "" + response.code());
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        TypeAdapter<Limit> adapterrr = gson.getAdapter(Limit.class);
                        try {
                            Limit limit;

                            if (response.errorBody() != null)
                                limit =
                                        adapterrr.fromJson(
                                                response.errorBody().string());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        System.out.println("d5aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaal");
                        System.out.println("c bn d5al");
                        limits = response.body();
                        System.out.println(response.body());

                  for (Limit l : response.body()) {
    //
    //                          System.out.println(l.getRefpeak());
    //                            System.out.println(p.getPeak());

    //                            rms.add(new Entry(p.getRms(), i));
    //                            ku.add(new Entry(p.getKu(), i));
    //                            peak.add(new Entry(p.getPeak(), i));
    //                            cf.add(new Entry(p.getCf(), i));
    //                            ovelo.add(new Entry(p.getOvelo(), i));
    //                            b1.add(new Entry(p.getB1(), i));
    //                            b2.add(new Entry(p.getB2(), i));
    //                            b3.add(new Entry(p.getB3(), i));
    //                            b4.add(new Entry(p.getB4(), i));
    //                            b5.add(new Entry(p.getB5(), i));
    //                            b6.add(new Entry(p.getB6(), i));
    //                            speed.add(new Entry(p.getSpeed(), i));
    //                            i++;
                          }


                        }





                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                        //avi.hide();
                        System.out.println("faiiiilure");
                        System.out.println("KAKA" + t.toString());
                    }
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("onResponse", "There is an error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

whats wrong with my code?
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPVm9.jpg

Answer (score 0):

If you get a response with status code = 500 which refers to "internal server error" error, then this could be the server didn't handle well with your data sent in the request.
To know more detail, you can log all the parameters to sent to server:

```
pf.getString("login","")
pf.getString("ip","")
...
```

Then compare with parameters sent in the Postman.

[More detail about error 500](https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938)

Comment: i passed the parameters statically and nothing has changed,i got the same error.

Comment: Can you control server? If yes, you can see the detail error in the server

Comment: i'm using node.js,no error in server just passing the right parameters with 500 code.

Comment: i got a similar action in the same activity and it work,i dont know whats the problem with this.

Comment: How about LoginActivity.adresseLocal? are they the same?

Comment: yes its a static variable for all the application,i show all the parameters in system.out.println and they are all correct